# Noun phrases with infinitivals: "Deutsch lernen"

Tags: infinitive

I'm thinking about what kinds of phrases I can put after "bei" as in the following example:

> Sie hilft mir beim Deutsch lernen.

I never learned noun phrase constructions with infinitivals, and I'm wondering what the rules are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct *beim* + *Verb* triggers the [nominalization](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung) of the verb. In your example the verb is *lernen* and has to be capitalized as it becomes a noun. Omitting *Deutsch* for the moment:

> Sie hilft mir beim Lernen.

In your example, there is another noun which builds a composite noun with *Lernen*. And as you might know, composite nouns in German are created by putting the words together. Your sentence thus becomes:

> Sie hilft mir beim Deutschlernen.

So the rule for the nominalization of phrases *Object* + *Infinitive* is: put the words together, start with a capital letter. Examples:

> Hecke schneiden
>
> Spaghetti kochen

Become:

> Er schwitzt beim Heckeschneiden.
>
> Die Küche wird warm beim Spaghettikochen.